# Glossary view preview works fine but it is not visible on actual page.why?

Tags: views

I had cloned a **glossary view** but forgot to update the page path.

Later I deleted the cloned view. Now none of my newly created views work! 
Preview displays properly but nothing is displayed on actual page.Please help me.

I tried clearing all caches,disabling/reverting the original `glossary view` ,disabling `field group module` as suggested in one of the post but nothing works.